# Inverse of element-wise positive matrices inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-equations

Consider two matrices A and B that satisfy the inequality $A \leq B$ (the relation $\leq$ is understood element-wise). The matrices A and B are positive (there elements are positive). Under which conditions do we have $A^{-1} \geq B^{-1}$ please? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @AlgebraicPavel. I have corrected the typo in the question now.

Comment: A simple condition is both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal.

Comment: Thank you @AlexRavsky. You are right, thanks. What about the more general case in which the matrices A and B are not diagonal?